# How do i remove a specific collection from my model in C#

Tags: c#, models

This is my model:

```
    public class ObsModel : BindableBase
    {


        private String _ObsName = string.Empty;
        public string ObsName
        {
            get { return this._ObsName; }
            set { this.SetProperty(ref this._ObsName, value); }
        }

        private String _ObsColor = string.Empty;
        public string ObsColor
        {
            get { return this._ObsColor; }
            set { this.SetProperty(ref this._ObsColor, value); }
        }

        private String _ObsValue = string.Empty;
        public string ObsValue
        {
            get { return this._ObsValue; }
            set { this.SetProperty(ref this._ObsValue, value); }
        }
}
```

I can then populate my model using this object.

```
ObservableCollection<ObsModel> LastObsResults = new ObservableCollection<ObsModel>();
```

But how can I remove a particular collection if I have for example the observation name as a string variable by using the code below?

```
LatsObsResults.Remove( What DO I PUT HERE);
```

Comment: Overide the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods that compare `_ObsName

Comment: Ok just to make sure, you have the `ObsModel.ObsName` and want to remove the corresponding `ObsModels` with that name?

Comment: yes I want to remove everything associated with that obsname

Comment: Possible duplication (with solution): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118513/removeall-for-observablecollections This also avoids recreate the collection and allow you to remove one or a list of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remove an object from the collection by passing in the object to remove. This can be done through Linq like so:

`LastObsResults.Remove(LastObsResults.FirstOrDefault(obs => obs.ObsName == name));`

Comment: sorry but I am new to this what is obs supposed to be based on my code

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses LINQ `.Where` to produce the valid subset of your results, then assigns that subset to a new ObsevableCollection.  I am using the [constructor that accepts an `IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var validSubset = LastObsResults.Where(obs => obs.ObsName != name);
LastObsResults = new ObservableCollection<ObsModel>(validSubset);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var lastObsUpdated = LastObsResults.Except(model => model.ObsName == "Whatever")
                                   .ToList()
                                   .AsObservable();
```

This will create you an updated ObservableCollection with all but a named item.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove all items you can use this:

```
LastObsResults .Clear();
```

If you want to create your own extension method you could do something like this:

```
public static class ObservableCollectionExtensions
{
    public static int Remove<T>(
        this ObservableCollection<T> coll, Func<T, bool> condition)
    {
        var itemsToRemove = coll.Where(condition).ToList();

        foreach (var item in itemsToRemove)
        {
            coll.Remove(item);
        }

        return itemsToRemove.Count;
    }
}
```

With the extension above you can remove all items that match the condition passed. Example:

LastObsResults.Remove(x=> x.ObsName == myName);

And finally, you could use the existing collection.Remove() method but make sure you use it like [**described here**](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/tirthacs/remove-an-item-form-observable-collection-using-remove/) to avoid a very common issue.