# How to remove items from the observed list in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, observable, unirx

When I try to remove some elements of a list using the UniRx library, I'm getting the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

This is the code responsible of the removal:

```
Observable
    .EveryUpdate()
    .SelectMany(_ => _gameState.enemies)
    .Where(enemy => enemy.x > 5)
    .Subscribe(enemy =>
    {
        _gameState.enemies.Remove(enemy);
    })
```

One possible solution is to generate a new List as result of `SelectMany`, such as `_gameState.enemes.ToList()`, but I was wondering if there's an allocation-free alternative.

In case there is not, what other approaches are there while using observables to achieve this?

Comment: You are not allocation free like this anyway. Just get your items after the `Where` and perform your removal from that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly the `_gameState.enemies` is actually a plain `List` of some enemy instances.

I think you just overcomplicated it by chaining the subscription that way.

To me it looks like [`RemoveAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall) would be your best option

```
Observable.EveryUpdate().Subscribe(() => 
{
    _gameState.enemies.RemoveAll(enemy => enemy.x > 5);
});
```

---

Update as to the comment:

Since `_gameState.enemies` is a `RectiveCollection<Enemy>` you could indeed use (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15277219/7111561)

```
Observable.EveryUpdate().Subscribe(() => 
{
    for (int i = _gameState.enemies.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (_gameState.enemies[i].x > 5)
        {
            _gameState.enemies.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
});
```

or have this as extension method of course

Comment: `_gameState.enemies` is actually a `ReactiveCollection<Enemy>`, but simplifying the subscription did the trick. I'm using a plain for loop (iterating backwards) to remove the elements one by one since `RemoveAll` is not available in `ReactiveCollection`. Alternatively, there's this extension method https://stackoverflow.com/a/5118635/2886688

Comment: @EduardoPáezRubio thanks for the feedback! I added your input to the answer for future readers